# subprocess.run() doesn't return stdout or stderr

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I tried using `subprocess.run` [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760517/492336), but it doesn't return anything for stdout or stderr:

```
>>> result = subprocess.run('echo foo', shell=True, check=True)
>>> print(result.stdout);
None
>>> print(result.stderr);
None
```

I also tried using `capture_output=True` but I got an exception `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'`, even though it is described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: `capture_output=True` is for Python 3.7+

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had made a mistake, I hadn't added `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`:

```
result = subprocess.run('echo foo', shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
```

Now it's working.

Comment: You might want to set `stderr` as well.

Comment: capture_output keyword argument for subprocess.run is only available since python 3.7. You may be using an earlier version. Anyway, capture_output is equivalent to setting both  stdout and strerr to subprocess.PIPE